# Represent the statements into symbolic form as follows

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Represent the statement below into symbolic form (without any word) using quantifiers such that the $"\neg"$ symbol is not used at the beginning statement.

"Graph of functions $y=x^2+x+2$ and $y=x-2$ are not intersects".

How to do it?
Should I define first the equation of functions? But I also got confusing.
Any ideas?

**Attempt**:
Let $P(x,y)$ be the statement "$y=x^2+x+2$" and $Q(x,y)$ be the statement "$y=x-2$". Let $\Bbb R$ be the universe. Then
$$(\forall x)(\forall y)\overline{P(x,y) \wedge Q(x,y)}.$$

Or

Let $P(x,y)$ be the statement $"y=x^2+x+2=x-2"$. Let $\Bbb R$ be the universe. Then
$$(\forall x,y)\overline{P(x,y)}.$$

Does these true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let f(x)=x^2+x+2 and g(x)=x-2. If you want to be less precise, let ‘H(x,y)’ be the predicate “x is a graphical point of intersection with y”. Then, we can define your sentence as:

∀x∀y(x,y∈ℝ—>~(H(f(x),g(y))v
H(g(y),f(x)))).

If you want to more precision, you can say:

∀x∀y(x,y,∈ℝ—>~((f(x)=y—>~(g(x)=y))—>
(H(f(x),g(y))vH(g(y),f(x)))))

If you don’t want to explicitly mention that the *graphs* don’t intersect, then you can simply say:

∀x∀y(x,y,∈ℝ—>(f(x)=y—>~(g(x)=y))).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What if the negation symbol is used at the beginning of sentences?

Comment: Why was the first not: $\forall x \forall y (x \in \Bbb R \implies H(f(x),(y).s

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you help me?